# Can this be done entirely via linq?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a process where I identity rows in a list (unmatchedClient) then call a separate method to delete them (pingtree.RemoveNodes). This seems a little long winded and I could acheive the same thing by merely setting the value of the property "DeleteFlag" to true. But how do I set the value using linq?

```
var unmatchedClient = pingtree.Nodes.Where(x =>
    _application.LoanAmount < x.Lender.MinLoanAmount ||
    _application.LoanAmount > x.Lender.MaxLoanAmount ||
    _application.LoanTerm < x.Lender.MinLoanTerm ||
    _application.LoanTerm > x.Lender.MaxLoanTerm)
.Select(x => x.TreeNode)
.ToList();

pingtree.RemoveNodes(unmatchedClient);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Consider answers to question [Assigning values inside a LINQ Select?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16594544/assigning-values-inside-a-linq-select/16594770#16594770) before picking a solution to your problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like this?

```
pingtree.Nodes.Where(x =>
        _application.LoanAmount < x.Lender.MinLoanAmount ||
        _application.LoanAmount > x.Lender.MaxLoanAmount ||
        _application.LoanTerm < x.Lender.MinLoanTerm ||
        _application.LoanTerm > x.Lender.MaxLoanTerm)
        .Select(x => x.TreeNode)
        .ToList()
        .ForEach(n=> n.DeleteFlag = true);
```

Answer (score 3):

> But how do I set the value using linq

You don't. Period.

Linq is a *query* language and querying is reading.

There is a back door that some people abuse to set values. In your case it would look like:

```
pingtree.Nodes.Where(...)
              .Select(n => { n.DeleteFlag = true; return n; }
```

but this really is not done. Firstly because it is unexpected. Linq methods, including `Select`, are supposed to leave the source collection unchanged. Secondly because the statement itself does not do anything because of deferred execution. You'd have to force execution (e.g. by `ToList()`) to make it effective.

Maybe this looks like nitpicking, but when queries get a bit more complex it becomes a major point. It is not uncommon to do a projection (`Select`) followed by a filter (`Where`). You could have decided to do a filtering (where n.Deleted == false) after the projection for instance.

So, you query the objects using linq and then loop through them to do whatever needs to be done. `ToList().ForEach()` is one of the methods you can use to do that.

Side node: the back door that I showed would throw exceptions when using linq-to-sql or entity framework.