# Linq - how to replace a lists property with value from another list where both keys are equal

Tags: c#, linq

I have 2 lists groupoptions and dataIndicator

```
class groupoptions{
  ...
  GroupName string
}

class dataIndicator{
  ...
 HeaderID int
 IndicatorDescription
}
```

currently my groupname possible values are 4 or 5 or 11

first i want to get all dataindicators where headerid  is equal to GroupName, then replace those GroupNames with dataindicator's IndicatorDescription

What would be the Linq syntax for this?

**UPDATE**

using join

```
var newList = from first in dataIndicator
                      join second in groupedoptions
                      on first.HeaderID.ToString() equals second.GroupName
                      select new { first,second };
```

What next?
PROBLEM: i want to do it inside a constructor that is being created inside a Linq Select

```
var list = xyz.Select(x => new groupoptions(){
   GroupName = x.Key.ToString();
 })
```

Comment: What have you tried and in what way is it not working?

Comment: i am using dataIndicator.GetEnumerator but want a one/two line linq syntax

Comment: havent used (getenumerator) yet

Comment: Could you please provide valid C# code and some sample data (also in C#)?

Comment: code is updated let me know if u require something else

Comment: Does it need to be done with Linq? Is that a requirement?

Comment: no just wanted to write little efficient code but seems its not a good idea -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16594544/assigning-values-inside-a-linq-select

Comment: why not just do a simple for loop? just as short as LINQ and gets the job done.  Might have different performance I suppose if you have massive data sets.

Comment: my question was probably not clear enough i want to do it inside the constructor that is inside a select [check update]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my problem was i wanted to do it inside a constructor that was being created inside a Linq Select...i did the following instead of join

```
var list = xyz.Select(x => new groupoptions()
        {      
          GroupName = dataIndicator.Where(d => d.IndicatorID.ToString().Equals(x.Key.ToString())).First().IndicatorDescription
            }
```

P.S. First is taken because there will always be one record that matches..Also i was doing a mistake of comparing with headerid when i should have compared to indicatorid property.

Answer (score 1):

this little for loop gets what you are looking to do done in just a few lines. No need to use linq if all you're looking to do is be efficient.

```
class ConsoleApplication1
{
    public static void Main()
    {

        List<groupOptions> g = new List<groupOptions>();
        List<dataIndicator> d = new List<dataIndicator>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            g.Add(new groupOptions() { groupName = i.ToString() });
            d.Add(new dataIndicator() { headerID = i, indicatorDescription = "id:" + i});
            Console.Write(g[i].groupName + ":");
            Console.WriteLine(d[i].headerID);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("enter to change");
        Console.ReadLine();
```

this is the pertinent part:

```
        for(int i = 0; i < g.Count(); i++)
        {
            if (g[i].groupName == d[i].headerID.ToString())
                g[i].groupName = d[i].indicatorDescription;
        }
```

the rest just is just to make sure it worked.

```
        for(int i = 0; i < d.Count(); i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(g[i].groupName);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class groupOptions
{

    public string groupName { get; set; }

}


class dataIndicator
{
    public int headerID { get; set; }
    public string indicatorDescription { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a non-linq example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication5
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var groupOptions = new List<GroupOption>();
            groupOptions.Add(new GroupOption { GroupName = 4.ToString() });
            groupOptions.Add(new GroupOption { GroupName = 5.ToString() });
            groupOptions.Add(new GroupOption { GroupName = 11.ToString() });

            var dataIndicators = new List<DataIndicator>();
            dataIndicators.Add(new DataIndicator { HeaderID = 4, IndicatorDescription = "four" });
            dataIndicators.Add(new DataIndicator { HeaderID = 99, IndicatorDescription = "ninetynine" });
            dataIndicators.Add(new DataIndicator { HeaderID = 100, IndicatorDescription = "onehundred" });

            Console.WriteLine("Before:");
            PrintGroupOptions(groupOptions);

            foreach (var dataIndicator in dataIndicators)
            {
                foreach (var groupOption in groupOptions)
                {
                    if (dataIndicator.HeaderID.ToString() == groupOption.GroupName)
                    {
                        groupOption.GroupName = dataIndicator.IndicatorDescription;
                    }
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("After:");
            PrintGroupOptions(groupOptions);
        }

        static void PrintGroupOptions(List<GroupOption> groupOptions)
        {
            groupOptions.ToList().ForEach(g => Console.WriteLine(g));
        }
    }

    class GroupOption
    {
        public string GroupName { get; set; }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return GroupName;
        }
    }

    class DataIndicator
    {
        public int HeaderID { get; set; }
        public string IndicatorDescription { get; set; }
    }
}
```