# Linq query with Groupby Select and foreach loop

Tags: linq

```
 List<APList> List = new List<APList>() --

List = statement.APList.Where(f => f.PeriodKey == periodkey
                                 && f.ClassKey == classkey
                                 && f.ClassKey != null)
                        .GroupBy(g => new { g.PostKey})
                        .Select(s => s.First()).ToList();

foreach (var item in List)
{
    item.ClassKey = null;
} 

--data 

periodkey(int)  postkey(int)   classkey(int?)       
101          12        10
100          12        11
101          11        10
100          11        11




--expected 

periodkey  postkey   classkey       
101          12        null
100          11        null
```

This is working but i dont want to use foreach loop .Is there a better way to optimize the query and write it in a single linq query using Lambda expressions.

Comment: .List().Foreach().ForEach(s=>s.ClassKey = null)  gives me cannot implicitly convert void to system.collection.generic<List>.

Comment: Edit your question and show the code that throws the exception and the exception.

Comment: Why you need item.ClassKey = null if in your Where clouse you have f.ClassKey != null ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply select classKey as `null`

```
List = statement.APList.Where(f => f.PeriodKey == periodkey
                                 && f.ClassKey == classkey
                                 && f.ClassKey != null)
                        .GroupBy(g => new { g.PostKey})
                        .Select(s => s.First())
                        .Select(i => new APList() {
                            PeriodKey = i.PeriodKey,
                            ClassKey = null,
                            /* ... */
                        })                            
                        .ToList();
```

Comment: i didnt realize i can do another select and use AnonymousType to explicitly set the values which i am doing using foreach loop. Cheers

Comment: this is no anonymous type, but strongly typed.

Comment: yes , but i do need to pass other keys as well except null . Cheers

Answer (score 0):

As per the answers on ([Assigning values inside a LINQ Select?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16594544/assigning-values-inside-a-linq-select)), a `foreach` loop (or `.ForEach`) is better than using LINQ because LINQ is meant for querying objects, not mutating them.

If you do want to replace the loop, you could instead use

```
List = statement.APList.Where(f => f.PeriodKey == periodkey
                             && f.ClassKey == classkey
                             && f.ClassKey != null)
                       .GroupBy(g => new { g.PostKey})
                       .Select(s => s.First())
                       .ToList();

List.ForEach(i => i.ClassKey = null);
```

The `.ForEach` must be on a separate line because it performs an action for each item in `List` and returns void, not the list of items.

Answer (score 0):

You can just group them by period- and postkeys

```
var result = statement.APList.Where(ap => ap.PeriodKey == periodkey)
                             .Where(ap => ap.ClassKey == classkey)
                             .Where(ap => ap.ClassKey != null)
                     .GroupBy(ap => new { ap.PeriodKey, ap.PostKey })
                     .Select(group => group.Key);
```

Now result contains anonymous objects of unique `periodKey` and `postKey`.
You can use them to not mixed it with already existed class which contains `classKey`.

Or if you still want use already existed object then create new instance of this class with `classKey` set to `null`

```
var finalResult = result.Select(group => new AP 
                                { 
                                    PeriodKey = group.PeriodKey,
                                    PostKey = group.PostKey
                                })
                        .ToList();
```

Using `.ForEach` extension method will not be optimizing because it will do same `foreach` loop, as other Linq extension methods.